# Intercept errors in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In angular there is one feature call HttpInterceptor which intercepts Http request and it helps in converting http request before sending and after getting the response from the server.
Is there something similar in React Js??

I would like to have the code centralised so that can be managed from one place.

Comment: Not in React itself. There are error boundaries, and there are a lot of libraries that can help with that, but React itself does not have such a mechanism.

Comment: What Jonas said. I recommend using something like axios to create interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't do http calls. It's just a UI library.
For data fetching you can use `fetch`, `axios`, etc.
Axios has interceptors: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors